# WP_Query orderby date not working

Tags: wp-query, order, date

I have a simple WP_Query to get a list of posts of co-author (taxonomy *author*) order by date, this is the query :

```php
$username = get_the_author_meta( 'login', $author_id );
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'any',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  //'orderby' => 'post_date',
  'order'   => 'DESC',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'author',
      'field' => 'name',
      'terms' => $username
      )
  )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The result is always a list of posts ordering by date ASC... I have already search solution over internet without success...
Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You want to order by date with DESC order ? Maybe you've a plugin or the theme interfering with the query? What happens if you use `'suppress_filters' => true` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will definitely work....It worked for me...

```php
$username = get_the_author_meta( 'login', $author_id );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'tax_query' => array(
     array(
           'taxonomy' => 'author',
           'field' => 'name',
           'terms' => $username
          )
     )
);
                
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Is not working for me..

Comment: add this one in the args 'suppress_filters' => true,

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
'suppress_filters' => true
```

into the `$args` array did sorting in the order I needed.

Comment: This is an indication that a plugin or theme hook is modifying the query.

Comment: Check if you have Post Types Order plugin installed or any other plugin disable it. then query works fine

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Post Types Order plugin, you may need to add the following to your query args:

```
'ignore_custom_sort' => true,
```